Hula Hoop Kinetics
In the images below, a Hula-Hoop ring of mass m and large radius R rolls and precesses without sliding around a fixed cylinder of radius r, as shown.
Assume that for steady HulaHooping the weight of the Hula Hoop is balanced by a
frictional force at the rolling contact point A. Assume the
tube cross-section (small) radius of the Hula Hoop is much
smaller than the large radius R.
Can someone explain conceptually the difference between a simple spinning top precession and this case - where there is frictional force balancing the gravity



"please explain how they expand" You haven't even provided the formula at all.

I have edited the question now, I'm more interested in the theory as to the effects of balancing out gravity
